# show background shadow on line in bar with line chart in amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Currently, I have a chart which is combination of bar and line chart and I want to show the shadow on line chart is there any way to show the shadow on background 
here is the sample code to create line chart[image]

```
                objGraph.fillAlphas = 0;
                objGraph.lineAlpha = 0.7;
                objGraph.type = "line";
                objGraph.title = "îàæï";
                objGraph.lineThickness = 4;
                //objGraph.lineColor = "#" + 
                objChartData.lstSerieses[j].Color;
                objGraph.lineColor = "#fff";
                //objGraph.customBullet = "images/star.png"; // bullet for all data points
                objGraph.bullet = "round";
                objGraph.bulletSize = 11;
                objGraph.bulletColor = "#fff";
                objGraph.bulletBorderColor = "#000";
                objGraph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
                objGraph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
                //objGraph.bulletSize = 14; // bullet image should be a 
               rectangle (width = height)
                objGraph.customBulletField = "bullet"; // this will make the graph to display custom bullet (red star)
                objGraph.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize";
                objGraphdescriptionField = "description";
```

Comment: Check out this link https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/adding-a-shadow-to-line-graph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to make a shadow over the line in a line chart. First, you have to make a JSON object which is used to create a shadow like

```
     var defs = {
        "filter" : {
            "id": "dropshadow",  // id for the line shadow
            "x": "-10%",   // position from x axis
            "y": "-10%",   // position from y axis
            "width": "120%", // width of shadow
            "height": "120%",  //height of shadow
            "feOffset": {
              "result": "offOut",
              "in": "SourceAlpha",
              "dx": "0",  //position from adjecent line along x axis
              "dy": "12"  //position from adjecent line along y axis
            },
            "feGaussianBlur": {
              "result": "blurOut",
              "in": "offOut",
              "stdDeviation": "5"
            },
            "feBlend": {
              "in": "SourceGraphic",
              "in2": "blurOut",
              "mode": "normal"
            }
        }
    };
```

then simply you just need to add that JSON object to chart when you have bind the chart data like

```
chart.defs = defs;  //def object
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("amchartdiv", chart, theme);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<filter id="shadow">
    <feDropShadow dx="1" dy="5" stdDeviation="2"/>
</filter>
```

Make a function using given filter and pass it in the line using filter id #shadow.